# How do I use $File::Find::prune?

Tags: perl

I have a need to edit cue files in the first directory and not go recursively in the subdirectories.

```
find(\&read_cue, $dir_source);
sub read_cue {
    /\.cue$/ or return;

    my $fd = $File::Find::dir;
    my $fn = $File::Find::name; 
    tie my @lines, 'Tie::File', $fn
      or die "could not tie file: $!";

    foreach (@lines) {
        s/some substitution//;
    }

    untie @lines;
}
```

I've tried variations of

```
$File::Find::prune = 1;
return;
```

but with no success. Where should I place and define `$File::Find::prune`?

Thanks

Comment: Please edit your question to help us understand the layout of the directory tree with your cue files. Do you know which directory they're in beforehand? Are you using File::Find because they're at some unknown depth?

Answer (score 7):

If you don't want to recurse, you probably want to use [glob](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html):

```
for  (glob("*.cue")) {
   read_cue($_);
}
```

Comment: I've never used the 'glob' function and have no idea where to put your suggestion in the sub.

Comment: @thebourneid The code from msw replaces your call to `find()`. Then simply remove the first 3 lines from your `read_cue() method` -- that is, all of the stuff related to `File::Find`, which is the wrong tool for the job in this case.

Comment: As I already pointed out in another comment ... only that `glob` gets thoroughly confused with blanks spaces inside the file/path segments.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to filter the subdirectories recursed into by File::Find, you should use the preprocess function (not the $File::Find::prune variable) as this gives you much more control.  The idea is to provide a function which is called once per directory, and is passed a list of files and subdirectories; the return value is the filtered list to pass to the wanted function, and (for subdirectories) to recurse into.

As msw and Brian have commented, your example would probably be better served by a glob, but if you wanted to use File::Find, you might do something like the following.  Here, the preprocess function calls -f on every file or directory it's given, returning a list of files.  Then the wanted function is called only for those files, and File::Find does not recurse into any of the subdirectories:

```
use strict;
use File::Find;

# Function is called once per directory, with a list of files and
# subdirectories; the return value is the filtered list to pass to
# the wanted function.
sub preprocess { return grep { -f } @_; }

# Function is called once per file or subdirectory.
sub wanted { print "$File::Find::name\n" if /\.cue$/; }

# Find files in or below the current directory.
find { preprocess => \&preprocess, wanted => \&wanted }, '.';
```

This can be used to create much more sophisticated file finders.  For example, I wanted to find all files in a Java project directory, without recursing into subdirectories starting with ".", such as ".idea" and ".svn", created by IntelliJ and Subversion.  You can do this by modifying the preprocess function:

```
# Function is called once per directory, with a list of files and
# subdirectories; return value is the filtered list to pass to the
# wanted function.
sub preprocess { return grep { -f or (-d and /^[^.]/) } @_; }
```

Comment: +1 The `$File::Find::prune` var is evil and has wasted enough of my time! Thanks for this answer!!

Comment: What is evil about the prune variable?

Answer (score 1):

If you only want the files in a directory without searching subdirectories, you don't want to use File::Find. A simple [glob](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html) probably does the trick:

```
my @files = glob( "$dir_source/*.cue" );
```

You don't need that subroutine. In general, when you're doing a lot of work for a task that you think should be simple, you're probably doing it wrong. :)

Comment: ... only that `glob` gets thoroughly confused with blanks spaces inside the file/path segments.

Answer (score -1):

Say you have a directory subtree with

```
/tmp/foo/file.cue
/tmp/foo/bar/file.cue
/tmp/foo/bar/baz/file.cue
```

Running

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

use File::Find;

sub read_cue {
  if (-f && /\.cue$/) {
    print "found $File::Find::name\n";
  }
}

@ARGV = (".") unless @ARGV;
find \&read_cue => @ARGV;
```

outputs

```
found /tmp/foo/file.cue
found /tmp/foo/bar/file.cue
found /tmp/foo/bar/baz/file.cue
```

But if you remember the directories in which you found cue files

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

use File::Find;

my %seen_cue;
sub read_cue {
  if (-f && /\.cue$/) {
    print "found $File::Find::name\n";
    ++$seen_cue{$File::Find::dir};
  }
  elsif (-d && $seen_cue{$File::Find::dir}) {
    $File::Find::prune = 1;
  }
}

@ARGV = (".") unless @ARGV;
find \&read_cue => @ARGV;
```

you get only the toplevel cue file:

```
found /tmp/foo/file.cue
```

That's because `$File::Find::prune` emulates the `-prune` option of `find` that affects *directory* processing:

> #### -prune
>
> True; if the file is a directory, do not descend into it.

Comment: either your question is really unclear, either your answer does not work. OK, you prune subdirectories, but parallel directories will still be searched (just replace your %seen_cue hash with a simple scalar to change that). Also as others pointed out this solution looks overly complex to look in only one directory.